# How do I create a console command (rake task) in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I used Gii to create this file, but I cannot execute it from the console!

`controllers/KWController.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

class KWController extends \yii\console\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

When I try to run it, it fails.

```
$ yii kw
Error: Unknown command "kw".

$ yii Kw
Error: Unknown command "Kw".

$ yii kW
Error: Unknown command "kW".

$ yii kw/index
Error: Unknown command "kw/index".
```

The guide was of no help, as everything is in order.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to put the file in `commands/` path and change the namespace. Weird, the docs don't mention that at all. And why did Gii put it there?

Comment: This is how the basic app is configured. Checkout the `yii` file in your application root.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `yii2-app-basic` template, console commands go in the `commands` directory as controllers.

If you're using the `yii2-app-advanced` template, console commands go in the `console\controllers` folder.